# Method chaining within namespace

Tags: javascript, namespaces, method-chaining

I can't figure out how to chain methods within same namespace (I do not want to create a class but rather call it directly):

```
var namespace = {
    one: function(args) {
        // do something
    },
    two: function() {
        // do something in addition
    }
}

// call both
namespace.one(true).two();
```

Comment: `return this` would work in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return `namespace` or `this`.

```js
var namespace = {
    one: function(args) {
        // do something
        console.log('one');
        return this;
    },
    two: function() {
        // do something in addition
        console.log('two');
        return this;
    }
}

// call both
namespace.one(true).two();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a refernce to the namespace object to chain it.

```
var namespace = {
    one: function (args) {
       // Do something
       return this;
    },
    two: function () {
       // Do something
       return this;
    }
}
```